# Setting TextView to bold font with xml-attribute and custom font (not working)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm building an app and we're using a custom font called Apercu, which you might heard of. Anyway, I've built a util to help me set the font on all the elements.

This is how one of the methods in that util looks like (I also have methods for setting this font on a ViewGroup, where I loop through all elements):

```
public static void setApercuOnTextView(final TextView view, final Context context) {
    Typeface tmpTypeface = apercu;
    Typeface tmpTypefaceBold = apercuBold;

    if (tmpTypeface == null && tmpTypefaceBold == null) {
        apercu = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Apercu.otf");
        apercuBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Apercu-Bold.otf");
    }


    if (view.getTypeface() == Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD) {
        view.setTypeface(apercuBold, Typeface.BOLD);
    } else if (((TextView) view).getTypeface() == Typeface.DEFAULT) {
        view.setTypeface(apercu);
    }

}
```

My intention with this was that all TextViews that I set to bold in the xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

However, when I later in the code run this:

```
TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_textview);
Fonthelper.setApercuOnTextView(name, getActivity());
```

It does not enter the if-statement where I try to get all bold fonts... I've also tried with Typeface.BOLD, but it does not get into that if-statement anyways.

My custom solution at the moment is to do like this:

```
TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_textview);
name.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
Fonthelper.setApercuOnTextView(name, getActivity());
```

Does anyone have any clue on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:
   Make sure you are certain `view.getTypeface()` isn't `null`... When I outqouted `android:textStyle="bold"` no `Typeface` was found.

```
if (view.getTypeface() == null) {
    Log.e(this.class.getName(), "No textStyle defined in xml");
    // handle?
}
if (view.getTypeface().isBold()) {
    view.setTypeface(apercuBold, Typeface.BOLD);
} else if (((TextView) view).getTypeface() == Typeface.DEFAULT) {
    view.setTypeface(apercu);
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. very true! So how can I then find out if I have set the TextView to bold in the xml or not?

Comment: I've updated the answer, to check for `null` before handling the `getTypeface` result. I'm assuming you're not talking about in the xml, right? Since that's in your question...

Comment: Btw, look out for this `tmpTypeface == null && tmpTypefaceBold == null`, please change to `tmpTypeface == null || tmpTypefaceBold == null`... Otherwise you might get a `NullPointerException` if only one is `null`

Comment: Nice! Thanks! So then I probably have to set the Typeface in the code in order for this to work properly!

Comment: You at least have to be aware of the possible null values, but you can set it in the xml... That's no problem